# DS -160 form and fee for baby

Tags: visas, usa

Is separate DS -160 form needed for my baby for US B1/B2 visa? and should I pay a separate fee for him(= 160 US$)?

Comment: What is your nationaltiy, the nationality of the baby and the age of the baby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. A separate DS-160 must be filed for each person applying for a visa, including infants. See, for example, [this page](http://blogs.usembassy.gov/malaysia/tag/ds-160/): "[A]ll children need a visa for travel to the U.S." And you will need to pay the applicable visa fee for the child's nationality and visa type just like any other applicant.

Check the details on the website of your local consulate, but children 13 and under generally do not need to appear for the visa interview.

The US Department of State has [some tips](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/photos.html) on taking photos of young children for this purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I'm afraid so if your baby requires a B-1/B-2 visa, with some very exceptional exceptions. The current Nonimmigrant visa application processing fees (non-refundable) for all categories are set out [here](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/fees/fees-visa-services.html). Depending upon nationality a [Reciprocity fee](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/fees/fees-reciprocity-tables.html) may be payable in addition.

Answer (score 0):

The [CGI Federal](https://cgifederal.secure.force.com/) web site calculates all fees automatically and asks you to enter receipt numbers for all family members.

[image]

However, one person had [a problem](https://www.immihelp.com/forum/showthread.php/206772-Unable-to-schedule-H4-visa-appointment-for-spouse-using-my-profile-on-CGIFederal-site) when the web site asked to pay more.